# C#(loading search results in textbox)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to search the database and set the results in textboxes. I am
getting error, which says "invalid cast exception". I need your guide please.

```
private void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    string STR="select * from TICKETSALES where REFERENCE="+txtSearch.Text;
    cmd = new SqlCommand(STR,con );
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if(dr.Read())
    {
        txtTrans.Text = dr.GetInt32("TRANSACTIONNUMBER").ToString();
        txtPax.Text = dr.GetString("PASSENGERNAME");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ticket Number not Found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, before looking at the main problem, there is a real one, don't use the query like that, I mean don't pass the value directly in the query string because you are totally open to SQL Injection. use parameters to stay in the safe side !

Comment: if the field `REFERENCE` is of type `string` (i.e. `varchar/nvarchar`) then you should use `REFERENCE='"+txtSearch.Text+"'`. As every string should be kept inside a single quote(').

Comment: I can see so many problems with this code it hurts my eyes. Don't use underscore in identifier names (like `btn_search` I assume you have). Don't put SQL in your presentation layer (and do have layers to separate presentation from logic from data access). Don't use `SELECT *`, use specific column names instead. Don't concatenate user input with SQL. Don't use all-caps for identifier names, use camelCase. Add spaces after commas, and not before parenthesis (or add spaces after the opening parenthesis too). hth.

Comment: @TsahiAsher, your comments shows instructions for clean code. Kudos to your suggestions. I will follow your suggestions for my projects. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Modify your select statement to get required column details.
2. While assigning values to test box, use column index to get value from `dr`
3. Convert value to string assign it to respective textbox

Here is sample implementation

```
con.Open();
//Use of camelCasing. transactionNumber instead of TRANSACTIONNUMBER
string STR="select transactionNumber,passengerNumber from TICKETSALES where REFERENCE=@search";
cmd = new SqlCommand(STR,con );
cmd.Parameters.Add("@search", txtSearch.Text);
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if(dr.Read())
    {
        txtTrans.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[0]);
        txtPax.Text = Convert.ToString(dr[1]);
    }
```

Few tips for best coding practices (Credits: @[tsahi-asher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/767425/tsahi-asher))

- **Don't** pass values inside query, use parameters in query and use `Paramere.Add()` function to replace parameter with its value
- **Don't** put your sql statements in presentation layer. Have some dedicated layer of SQL.
- **Don't** use `select *`, use specific column name.
- **Don't** use all-caps for identifier names, use [camelCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149491/pascal-casing-or-camel-casing-for-c-sharp-code).

Comment: We still talking about SQL injection, and you made the same mistake and encourage him to keep going in the wrong way !

Comment: Please provide reason for downvote so I can improve my answer

Comment: I'm not your downvoter but I believe it's all about the old answer and prevent sql injection

Comment: It was me. I upvoted again. I actually wanted to comment on why, but SO blocked my comment, saying I shouldn't comment on my downvote, but only on answer improvement!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

- Note the sql injection protection by paramtising the sql query.

  ```
  private void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
      {
          string query = "select top 1 TRANSACTIONNUMBER, PASSENGERNAME from ticketsales where reference=@ref";
          using (SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con))
          {
              con.Open();
              DataTable dt = new DataTable();
              adap.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ref", txtSearch.Text.Trim());
              adap.Fill(dt);

              if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
              {
                  txtTrans.Text = dt.Rows[0]["TRANSACTIONNUMBER"].ToString().Trim();
                  txtPax.Text = dt.Rows[0]["PASSENGERNAME"].ToString().Trim();
              }
              else
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("Ticket Number not Found");
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There are few issue already mentioned in comments and posts. I will chip in my remarks - you don't dispose of unmanaged resources, one answer covers that, but it violates your code. So here is alternative solution:

```
SqlConnection con;
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataReader dr;

//some methods, fields

private void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    // as it has benn already said, you have to prevent yourself from SQL injection!
    cmd = (new SqlCommand("select * from TICKETSALES where REFERENCE=@ref", con)).Parameters.AddWithValue("@res", txtSearch.Text.Trim());
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.Read())
    {
        txtTrans.Text = dr.GetInt32("TRANSACTIONNUMBER").ToString();
        txtPax.Text = dr.GetString("PASSENGERNAME");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ticket Number not Found");
    }
}
// it looks like you have unamanaged resources held by fields in your form,
// so to release them you have to call their Dispose() method!
// normally you should use using keyword if they were used locally in a method, as other answer states
public void Dispose()
{
    base.Dispose();
    if (con != null) con.Dispose();
    if (cmd != null) cmd.Dispose();
    if (dr != null) dr.Dispose();
}
```